# Python is reusing variables from one instance of an object for a new one

Tags: python

Can anybody explain this behaviour?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x={}):
        self.x = x

var1 = A()
print '#1', var1.x
var1.x['key'] = 'value'
print '#2', var1.x

var2 = A()
print '#3', var2.x
```

What I expect:

```
#1 {}
#2 {'key': 'value'}
#3 {}
```

What it really does:

```
#1 {}
#2 {'key': 'value'}
#3 {'key': 'value'}
```

This changes everything:

```
var2 = A({})
```

Comment: That's one of the most common [python gotchas](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)

Comment: the most asked newbie question, see http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Comment: and I thought I was no newbee *facepalm* - it took me some time to spot this in my code

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 3):

The default argument is instantiated once when the function is defined. Every time you assign

```
self.x = x
```

you are assigning the instance variable self.x to the same dictionary (default x).
You can avoid this by putting:

```
def __init__(self, x=None):
   self.x = {} if x is None else x
```

so that a new dictionary is created each time the function is called with its default argument.